# Error dragging with Ctrl key being pressed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made two snippets, same code, one in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Andrew_Chen1/nx6yzdst/5/) and one as a Stack Snippet (see below). For some reason, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key + drag yields different results.

The JSFiddle won't fire my drag events if I am holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, but the Stack Snippet will. Can someone try running these? I thought this was a browser or computer problem but maybe not.

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var drag = d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", function() {
        console.log("start");
      })
      .on("drag", function() {
        console.log("dragging");
      })
      .on("end", function() {
        console.log("eneded");
      });

svg.append("g").call(drag).append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 10).attr("r", 8)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: When I open your JSFiddle in Chrome browser, I see that `start`, `dragging` and  `ended` are logged to the console (Developer tools), hence the drag events are fired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of D3 version [5.10.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v5.10.0) (introduced by d3-drag module version [1.2.4](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/releases/tag/v1.2.4) fixing GitHub issue [#62](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/issues/62)) events fired with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key being pressed are filtered out because—under certain circumstances—<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click should open the context menu instead. The docs on [`drag.filter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_filter) have you covered:

> *drag*.**filter**([*filter*]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/src/drag.js#L141)
>
> If *filter* is specified, sets the filter to the specified function and returns the drag behavior. If *filter* is not specified, returns the current filter, which defaults to:
>
> ```
> function filter() {
>   return !d3.event.ctrlKey && !d3.event.button;
> }
> ```
>
> If the filter returns falsey, the initiating event is ignored and no drag gestures are started. Thus, the filter determines which input events are ignored; the default filter ignores mousedown events on secondary buttons, since those buttons are typically intended for other purposes, such as the context menu.

As you can see this will ignore any events involving the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key being pressed. The snippet in your question uses D3 v5.2.0, though, which did not implement above mentioned change yet and, therefore, did also listen to events with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

To include those events you can easily provide your own filter which might just drop the `!d3.event.ctrlKey` part from the original filter:

```
.filter(function() { 
  return !d3.event.button;
})
```

Have a look at the following working demo:

```js
const drag = d3
  .drag()
  .filter(() => !d3.event.button)   // Specify the filter
  .on("start", () => console.log("start"))
  .on("drag", () => console.log("dragging"))
  .on("end", () => console.log("ended"))

d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")
  .call(drag)
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("r", 8);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.12.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using d3 version 5.7 with Angular and when I upgraded to Angular 8 the ctrl + drag stopped working. I did not upgrade d3. Added this filter and it fixed the problem. Thanks!